# Does cursor in mongo points to the same results?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

Is there a difference if I use cursor to refer to some results or not if I want to retrieve documents and total count of documents? (I am also using skip and limit params)

Is cursor returning the same number of docs in this case for totalCount and docs:

```
const builtQuery = { ... };

const myCursor = MyCollection.collection.find(builtQuery);
const totalCount = await myCursor.count();
const docs = await myCursor.skip().limit().toArray();
```

Is totalCount and docs done in the same request? How can I know that it will return the exact totalCount of the docs? What if requesting docs takes more time and the totalCount number is smaller or bigger that docs number.

Comment: No, there are 2 requests. You cannot. Than you have discrepancy. It's actually one of the reasons it's been deprecated.

Comment: @AlexBlex then I assume the only option is to use aggregation right?

Comment: I don't see how aggregation would help tbh.

Comment: I thought it's possible to do some magic in aggregation and return count then do the rest like limit and skip, but I am not that familiar with mongo

Comment: I am sure you need no magic. Why the exact number is so important? You are not using it in the second query. Is it just to show the number? What happens if the matching documents were added or removed a second after you sent the json/html to the client? they will see stale data anyway.